# 406 HTTP Response when calling POST method in C# Web API

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

Every time I make a POST request with Fiddler, an UnsupportedMediaTypeException is raised. Am I missing something?

The Controller:

```
    [Route("api/contacts")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]ContactDTO contact)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        //Other operations

        return Created(contact);
    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    }
```

[Fiddler request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDHSn.jpg)

Comment: Try it with the default setting first and see if it still works. If it does try to narrow down which line is the culprit. I suspect clearing the Supporting media types to be the source of your problem.

Comment: Are you using [HttpPostAttribute] on the action?

Comment: what request are you sending? show your complete request.

Answer (score 1):

After looking a bit further into my code, I noticed something. My controller class was inheriting from ODataController. I just changed the inheritance to ApiController and everything works fine now.